# WARNING: disabled use of C++11 features in Armadillo

Tags: c++, c++11, cygwin, armadillo

I am using Armadillo under windows and cygwin.

Despite, Armadillo is suggesting Mingw, Boost is suggesting cygwin and avoid using mingw. So, when I compile, I receive such warning. Is there anyway to fix this warning without hacking the soruce code of Armadillo?

The location of warning in the source code is [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp#L72).

main.cpp

```
#include <armadillo>

int main()
{
    arma::mat A(5,10);
    A.ones();
    return 0;
}
```

compile:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11
```

warning:

```
E:\test\temp>make
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -fdiagnostics-color=always
In file included from /usr/include/armadillo:50:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:72:123: note: #pragma message: WA
RNING: disabled use of C++11 features in Armadillo, due to incomplete support fo
r C++11 by Cygwin
     #pragma message ("WARNING: disabled use of C++11 features in Armadillo, due
 to incomplete support for C++11 by Cygwin")

                                           ^
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be a recent addition to Armadillo, but the following compile-time flag seems to do the trick:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -DARMA_DONT_PRINT_CXX11_WARNING
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Despite it removes the warning, it does not return back the C++ features. Maybe we still have to wait for new versions of Cygwin.

Comment: @ar2015  I see.  I didn't realize that was the case.  Before I use that flag, I get a different warning than the one your original post mentioned.  The one I see reads "WARNING: Cygwin may have incomplete support for C++11 features.".  I took that to mean the features were enabled, but Armadillo didn't guarantee their functionality.  I'm not familiar enough with C++11 to be able to really tell, though.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't program using Armadillo. But judging from Armadillo source code  @https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/, it seems that for all versions of Armadillo(6.1-6.5), C++11 is disabled for Cygwin.

Latest **Cygwin** includes **GCC-5.2** and **Cygwin-Gcc-4.9.2** (as well as Mingw @Cygwin) which should, IMHO, inherently support latest C++11 features.

Your best option is to delete the code block @[compiler_Setup.hpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp#L68-L74)

```
#if defined(__CYGWIN__)
  #if defined(ARMA_USE_CXX11)
    #undef ARMA_USE_CXX11
    #undef ARMA_USE_EXTERN_CXX11_RNG
    #pragma message ("WARNING: disabled use of C++11 features in Armadillo, due to incomplete support for C++11 by Cygwin")
  #endif
#endif
```

If that's not an option, you have to redefine `ARMA_USE_CXX11` and `ARMA_USE_EXTERN_CXX11_RNG`.

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
    #if (__GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && (__GNUC_MINOR__ > 8)))
            #define ARMA_USE_CXX11
            #define ARMA_USE_EXTERN_CXX11_RNG
    #endif
#endif
```

You can define it at@[RcppArmadilloForward.h](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h#L47) after the code `#include <armadillo>`

Answer (score 0):

Armadillo library identifies your compiler name with the help of predefined macros in the Cygwin compiler. You can `#undef` the `__CYGWIN__` macro in your code before including the library. There may be a issue if the compiler macro is undefined because this macro can be necessary in high-performance code that aims at using the best performance tricks available for each compiler